# Codenameone ComponentGroup is not displayed on the real ios device

Tags: ios, iphone, codenameone

I'm developing cross platform app with Codename One. For iOS version of my app I want to `ComponentGroup` would be shown on the form. I added `ComponentGroup` element in CN Designer tool and it's displayed normally on simulator. Then I installed my app on the real iPhone, and my form on it is different from the one I've created in Designer tool - `ComponentGroup` is not displayed. What I'm doing wrong?

[I want my form to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwGkS.png)

[This is how my form looks on real iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMCfS.jpg)

Comment: This seems to be a bug due to a set of new changes to the animation framework, it should be fixed with an hour or so.

Answer (score 1):

In your theme constant you have to set `ComponentGroupBool` to true.

Comment: I've set `ComponentGroupBool` to true, but `ComponentGroup` element is still not displayed on the real device